Tanstack Table: error "result is null" because of null values
I am building a table with tanstack/react-table, and want to have a column of a property (creditornumber) of the object (outlet). Some creditornumber are null, so I got the error of "result is null" as in the image.
{
accessorKey: "outlet.creditornumber",
        enableSorting: true,
        header: "creditor",
        cell: (node) =>  node.getValue();
       } 


Anyone know how to fix this error?
Thank you so much in advance
